# How to check delimiter of txt file in ubuntu

Tags: shell, ubuntu, awk, sed

I have .txt file and I want to check their delimiter.  File may have delimiter  tab, pipe(|) and comma

Tab separated file

```
ID  Name    Email
1   Test    a@test.com
2   testone b@test.com
```

Comma separated

```
ID,Name,Email
1,Test,a@test.com
2,testone,b@test.com
```

For above sample data I want to get delimiter. So for first sample delimiter is tab and for second delimiter is  comma(,)

Comment: All of above, and your use case is unclear (to me, anyway). What should happen if you have a pipe delimited file that has commas in the data fields? Rather than reply in comments, please update the body of your Q. Good luck.

Comment: @JamesBrown I have updated my question. Please check

Comment: upvoting a newbie question where they have listened to advice and improved the question! Keep posting, but always include small sample input, required output from same input, your code, current output and exact text of any error messages;-) ..... Good luck to all.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a very good question and I'd like to see other peoples' solutions as well. This is something one needs to wrestle with when automizing processing of sh***y data:

```
awk '
FNR==1 {                          # process the header record
    line=$0                       # duplicate to leave $0 usable
    
    gsub(/[^,|\t]/,"",line)       # remove non-candidates

    split(line,a,"")              # split leftovers

    delete b                      # ... since FNR...
    max=prev=0                    # reset
        
    for(i in a)                   # flip a and count hits
        b[a[i]]++
        
    for(i in b)                   # find max amount of hits
        if(b[i]>=b[max]) {        
            prev=max
            max=i
        }
    if(b[prev]==b[max]) {         # if count collision
        print "Multiple candidates for delimiter. Exiting."
        exit 1
    }
                                  # below: output 
    printf "Delimiter: %s\n",(max=="\t"?"\\t":(max==" "?"[space]":max))

    exit
}' file
```

Output for example:

```
Delimiter: \t
```

Comment: Ah, so you're avoiding problems with commas inside of fields by just parsing the header. Good idea!

Comment: @thanasisp `Multiple candidates for delimiter. Exiting,` Whoops, I need to fix that trailing comma.

Comment: Above code is a sample for detecting the possible delimiter. What I did not include was the possibility for human interference by forcing an override delimiter. At work I've used a lot of inhouse made delimiter detectors that read 1 or 10 records to detect the delimiter and they never work. Some of them use existing libs to detect and there's this one lib in python that always chooses comma if one. Usually if you introduce more than the header to detection, the commas and space and other natural language characters start messing with the selection (over here comma is the decimal separator).

Comment: So that's why I have a professional interest to see delimiter detecting solutions. :D

Comment: @thanasisp _I don't see that more lines could mess_ I'll edit a sample to the end of my answer. Also, training neural nets to detect delimiters sounds like a bit overkill.

Comment: Yeah, it says `pipe` for `|,|,|` and `,|,|,`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot be sure, consider this:

```
test,test|test,test|test
test,test|test,test|test
```

But you can have a good estimation. I would parse a sample of the file, e.g. first 10 lines with a script like this:

```
BEGIN {
   sep[","]   = "comma"
   sep["\\|"] = "pipe"
   sep["\t"]  = "tab"
}

{
    for (x in sep) {
        c = gsub(x,"&",$0)
        if (c) cnt[sep[x] " " (c+1)]++
    }
}

END {
    for (x in cnt) {
        if (max == "" || cnt[x] > max) {
            max = cnt[x]
            est = x
        }
    }
    print est
}
```

where we count lines where a candidate delimiter appeared for N times, excluding zero times, and we keep as the best guess whatever happened most in the file.

Example usage:

```sh
head file | awk -f tst.awk
```

It prints the estimated separator and the estimated number of fields. Example:

```
> cat file
1,2,3
1,2,3
> awk -f tst.awk file
comma 3
```

Comment: What does it produce on your "cannot be sure" file ;-? Otherwise, this is how I would have approached the problem. It might be good to include a few sample lines of the input as part of the output, so a case like "cannot be sure" would be obvious. Good luck to all.

Comment: Interesting question... you cannot be sure! again. The order of the associative array in awk is undetermined, so in case of draw, it's random. Of course a draw is the edge of the input space for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The rule how to find the delimiter is unclear.
The first delimiter found is given by

```
# Substitute a tab for the space in the next command
grep -Eom1 "[,| ]" file | head -1
```

Maybe you want the character after `ID`:

```
sed -rn '1s/..(.).*/\1/p' file
# Or after a word
sed -rn '1s/\w*(.).*/\1/p' file
```